# Excel VBA listview control gives "Invalid property value" error when setting width

Tags: excel, vba, listview, userform

This is the Listview Control 6.0 (SP6)

When Ever I try to add a column I don't see the columns, I realized that this maybe due to the fact that the width of the columns is 0.00 so I tried changing the width multiple ways. All Result in the same error

"Run time Error '380':
Invalid property value

```
Private Sub ListView41_Click()
    Dim width As Long
    width = 10
    With ListView41
    .View = lvwReport
    .HideColumnHeaders = False
    .ColumnHeaders.Clear
    .ColumnHeaders.Add 1, , "A"
    .ColumnHeaders(1).width = width
    .ColumnHeaders.Add 2, , "B", width
    End With

End Sub
```

The only time the error isn't given is when width = 0
My gut tells me there is some other property value causing this but I have no idea which property it could be.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I ran into this same issue recently when upgrading from Office 2010 to Office 2016 and I hope this answer will help anyone else who gets stuck with this frustrating problem.

A workaround that I have found which works fairly well is to auto set the width of each column.

Use: `Call SetWidth(Sheets("Menu").OLEObjects("ListView1").Object)` with the below function/sub and replace "ListView1" with the name of your ListView.

`LVSCW_AUTOSIZE = -1` sets the width based on the content of the columns and `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER = -2` sets the width based on the content of the column header

**EDIT:** The width of the column can be manually set with this function by putting the desired width in place of the `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER` variable!

```
Private Declare Function SendMessageLong Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                                            ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                                                            ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                                                            ByVal lParam As Long) _ As Long

Private Const LVM_FIRST = &H1000
Private Const LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH = (LVM_FIRST + 30)

Private Const LVSCW_AUTOSIZE = -1
Private Const LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER = -2

Sub SetWidth(LV As ListView)
For Each C In LV.ColumnHeaders
    Call SendMessageLong(LV.hwnd, LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH, C.Index - 1, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.ColumnWidths = "10;10"
```

or with absolute values in cm:

```
.ColumnWidths = "6 cm;0"
```

or with absolute values in inch

```
.ColumnWidths = "1.5 in;0"
```

Comment: I get the error "object doesn't support this property or method"